# Python: eval() that coerces values to floating point?

Tags: python, eval

Is there a way to execute an `eval`-like function that coerces its values to floating point?  I am hoping to

```
eval('1/3')
```

and have it return the floating point value .333333 rather than the integer value 0.

Comment: In Python... version...?

Comment: open to methods in any version of python.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Grab the compiler flag for `__future__.division`, pass it and your code to `compile()`, then run `eval()` on the returned code object.

**(note by mh)** This has the added advantage of not changing the division operation globally, which might have unexpected side effects. **(end note)**

```
>>> import __future__
>>> eval(compile('1/3', '<string>', 'eval', __future__.division.compiler_flag))
0.33333333333333331
```

Comment: This is perfect, exactly what I need.  Especially good is that it doesn't change the global environment, which could possibly have unexpected side effects in other parts of the program.  I'll update your example to explicitly show the import and use of the compiler flag.  Thanks!!

Comment: Oh, that's cute, just saw this.  :-)

Comment: Can I restrict the decimal places to two?

Comment: @Jim: [No.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 7):

You question is really: how can I get Python to do floating point division by default. The answer is:

```
from __future__ import division
```

Comment: actually no, I would if possible turn it on just for the evaluation of the entered expression.  But, not being able to do that, this will work just fine.  Thanks!

Comment: The `__future__` settings are per-module so you could do it in a separate module, but Ignacio's way is better.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is there is no float value in expression.

try this `eval('1/3.0')`

Answer (score 3):

This works by default on Python3

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Dec  8 2011, 15:26:51) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> eval("1/3")
0.3333333333333333
```

For Python2 you can pass `-Qnew` on the command line (which is equivalent to `from __future__ import division`

```
$ python -Qnew
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> eval("1/3")
0.3333333333333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Lafada's answer, if you're getting the input string from a variable:

```
>>> string = '1/3'
>>> print eval(string+'.0')
0.333333333333
```

Comment: Would fail on expressions such as `string = (1/3)`.

Comment: The expression `string=(1/3)` doesn't create a string. It calculates 1/3, produces an integer result of 0, then stores the result in a variable called string. So then eval(string+'.0') will be trying to concatenate integer zero with string `'.0'`. It will work if your input is an actual string that hasn't been evaluated to an integer beforehand.